# Input validation between 0 and 100

Tags: java

Im stuck in this activity, I need to test if a number input from the keyboard is valid, between 0 and 100. the problem is that, if someone types a negative number, it will print both "valid" and "not valid" I just want to print not valid, can someone help me?

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter a test score: ");

       double t = scan.nextDouble();


       if(t <= 100)
       {  
         System.out.println("Valid");
       }
        if(t > 0 )
       {  
         System.out.println("Not Valid");
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: dont compare doubles like that

Comment: Read up about the basic Java constructs. For example, if-else . Also, your code would print both even with positive numbers like 42...

Comment: and the if-else logic is incorrect... if i give 50  as input this prints "valid" and "not valid"... so it is valid or not?

Comment: Try to think how you will do manually, the condition are not exactly right...

Answer (score 1):

Such problems can be *easily* solved by ... just reading carefully what you wrote into your own program!

Meaning: you, as a human "run" that program. And you find:

First you check if the number is smaller than 100; to then print "Valid".

Afterwards you check if the number is bigger than 0; to then print "Not Valid".

Are you really that surprised that a number **in** that range (0, 100) is both Valid and Not-Valid at the same time?!

So, the answer is:

1. You have to **define** the range of valid and invalid numbers.
2. Then you use if + else to print that information to the user

In other words: before you even start programming, you need to clearly understand the "scope" of your problem. Don't expect that "just writing source code" determines the **rules** to work with. You need to make up the rules *before* coding!

And then, you maybe end up with:

```
if (t >= 0 && t <= 100) {
  System.out.println("Valid");
} else {
  System.out.println("Not valid");
}
```

Or maybe, something completely different. It depends on what you *think* the rules for being valid really are!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(t <= 100 && t > 0)
 {  
   System.out.println("Valid");
 }
else
 {  
   System.out.println("Not Valid");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate conditions. If you type -1, `t <= 100` evaluates to true, that's why you're getting `Valid` to print.

You should use AND `&&` to compare both conditions at the same time.

It should something like this:

```
if(t>0 && t<=100) {
    System.out.println("Valid");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Valid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to test for values between 0 and 100 being valid, then all else being not valid:

```
if (t >= 0 && t <= 100) {
    System.out.println("Valid");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not valid");
}
```